# Pull and display image on server:Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I have a url.

```
**"/deals/image/"+name**
```

name is a variable which gives the image name.

The view catering to this url is

```
def image(request,name = None):
    if name == None:
        name = "3gmjr0kme6_coffee-art.jpg"
    else:
        name = str(name)
    this_directory = settings.PROJECT_ROOT
    url = this_directory+"\\templates\\media\\images\\photos\\"
    full =url+name 
    image_data = open(full, "rb").read()
    return HttpResponse(image_data, mimetype="image/png")
```

The problem that I am facing is that it is unable to get this view because of the dot "." i.e. "/deals/image/some_image.jpg" is not able to find the view. How can i accout for the "."? or am i doing something wrong?

urls file is as follows

```
 url(r'^image/(\w+)$','image'),
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The regular expression used by Python (and therefore Django) are well documented, for example on the [Python home page](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html).

Comment: This is very well documented on djangoproject.com If you don't understand it there, how can we make you understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the URL configuration to something like this:

```
url(r'^image/([\w\.]+)$','image')
```

- The `[...]` part is a *character set*. It will match all characters inside.
- The `\w` is used to match normal characters (A to Z and a to z), digits and the underscore "_".
- The `\.` matches a literal dot.
- The `+` means one or more of the previous expression.

When the `\w` and `\.` is put together inside a character set (`[]`), it will match all characters and digits, as well as underscore and the dot. Putting the `+` after means that there has to be at least one character in the set.

Comment: sorry for my rude comment. I was stuck with the problem for some time. Thanks a lot for your help. But rest assured that I did try to understand it.